# How to take backup of before deleting using $pull in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have following query that deletes some inner json docs. I want to backup the docs which will be deleted by this query. Is there any way to take such backup in mongodb.

```
    db.dataDetails.update_many(
    {
        "uid": 
        { 
            "$gte": batchMin, 
            "$lt": batchMax 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        "$pull": 
        { 
            "s":
            { 
                "ad":
                { 
                    "$lte": cdate 
                }
            }, 
            "o": 
            { 
                "ad":
                { 
                    "$lte": cdate
                }
            }
        } 
    })
```